# Searching date within Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to search if a particular date is present within a pandas dataframe however, I see some strange behavior particular to date as below. I am new to python and pandas - so any help is appreciated.

Sample dataframe:

```
>>> hd.dtypes
    Date    datetime64[ns]
    NAV            float64
    dtype: object

>>> hd.head()
    Date            NAV
    2004-04-01      41.106
    2004-04-02      41.439
    2004-04-05      41.727
    2004-04-06      41.667
    2004-04-07      41.770
```

Basically I am trying to find a particular date "next_day" is present in `hd['Date']` as below.The code always returns `not present` which baffles me. I have tried to set `next_day` to the first date in the `hd` dataframe which should always satisfy - but it still shows `not present`.
However the code works when I use the non-datetime column:

```
>>> next_day = hd['Date'][0]
>>> if (next_day not in hd['Date']):
      print 'not present'
    else:
      print 'present'
>>> not present
>>>if (41.106 not in hd['NAV']):
     print 'not present'
   else:
     print 'present'
>>> present
```

Is it related to datetime conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that method to test you can use `isin`:

```
hd['Date'].isin([next_day])In [5]:

df['Date'].isin([next_day])
Out[5]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

the problem here is that you are trying to compare a single value with an array so you'll get unexpected results:

```
In [8]:

next_day in df['Date']
Out[8]:
False
In [7]:

next_day not in df['Date']
Out[7]:
True
```

also I can't reproduce your other assertion:

```
In [17]:

41.106 in df['NAV']
Out[17]:
False
```

So the correct method to use is `isin` and pass a series or list to check if the values in the passed in list exist in your Series as shown above, whatever result you are seeing is bogus and incorrect with respect to `41.106 not in hd['NAV']`.

You can use the `any` along with the `==` operator to check for membership:

```
In [18]:

next_day == df['Date']
Out[18]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
In [19]:

(next_day == df['Date']).any()
Out[19]:
True
```